Transporter Agent customization error: unable to modify dimensions
I have created a new AGV_Transporter agent and plan to use it as a transporter.After creation I planned to customize the dimensions of the transporter, but as soon as I try to set the length width or height, an error occurs which you can see in the screenshot.
Event Loop Exception Error getting custom type in EO_INDEX_ARG for Transporter - Agent Type class com.anylogic.objectmodel.elements.ActiveObjectClass cannot be cast to class com.anylogic.objectmodel.elements.graphical.OMEmbeddedObject (com.anylogic.objectmodel.elements.ActiveObjectClass is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @e350b40; com.anylogic.objectmodel.elements.graphical.OMEmbeddedObject is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @1e0b4072)
It only happens when I try to change the dimensions. Any ideas on how to fix this or what might be wrong with my approach?
Additional details:
AnyLogic 8 Professional 8.8.5 version
Build: 8.8.5.202310311100 x64
Operating System: Linux Ubuntu 22.04
I also ran Anylogic on Windows 11 and the same error occurred, so I don't think it's the operating system.
I would like to be able to customize the length, width and height of my transporter according to my original specifications, but so far unfortunately the transporter model has standard dimensions.
I also tried to set the transporter dimensions through the TransporterFleet block, but no matter how I change the values - the agent dimensions do not change.
Any help would be very helpful!

known bug, update to newer version :)

It would be better to [edit] to include some evidence to support this. Can you include a citation backing this up (such as a link to a GitHub issue or to official documentation that confirms that) so that people can more easily determine whether this is correct or not?

To my question I have attached a screenshot with the moment when this error occurred. All I can additionally describe:

I create a new agent called AGV_Transporter
Set the agent parameter in flowcharts as Transporter
I try to set the dimensions and get this error


he meant my reply :)
